# Owin AuthenticationMode Active and Passive for different path

Tags: asp.net, owin

I'm using Owin WsFederation authentication. For unauthorized users I want one path to be redirected to STS and another to return 401 response. Is it possible to set different AuthenticationMode for different path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "fork" the OWIN pipeline in order to configure middleware differently for different paths.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseErrorPage(new ErrorPageOptions());

    app.Map("active", active => 
    {
        active.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
                //TODO: Add other options.
            });
    });

    app.Map("passive", passive =>
    {
        passive.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                //TODO: Add other options.
            });
    });
}
```

This sample configures the "error page" middleware to run on all requests, then goes on to create two URL-mapped pipelines, one for requests which start `/active` and the other for paths which start `/passive`. Each of these mapped pipelines partially configure an OIDC authentication middleware, using the active and passive modes respectively.

This mechanism is designed to let you run different sets of middleware when requests come in on specific paths. Put common middleware before the mapped middleware to make it run on every request.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of - but you can add more than one instance of the middleware in the pipeline, using different AuthenticationType, and use them on the different routes.